# Cache non-SSL request with Service Worker

Tags: javascript, html, ssl, offline-caching, service-worker

Since [Service Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API) registration requires website to be served over HTTPS, Google Chrome throws an error when I try to add HTTP resource to [Cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache):

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com/sw.js' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://example.com/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

I want to cache main HTTP page (or at least 301 redirection to HTTPS) because for users it's difficult to type `https://` part, especially on mobile devices, to get access to cached version of my website, when offline.

Are there any workarounds to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe you can use an application cache manifest for the http version with a cached redirect to the https version.

Comment: @NielsHeisterkamp I can't do that, because to cache a resource, browser should first send a request to it. And this is a problem, because I can't send request to `http` from `https` page... The only way to do this (AFAIK) is open another window with `window.open`, but that would break user experience

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this problem can be solved via a service worker because there is no way to intercept requests to the http scheme. However, it looks like the [`Strict-Transport-Security` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/HTTP_strict_transport_security) could work.

If provided on a `https` response, it forces the browser to always use the `https` scheme to load the page--which should hit the service worker, if it's been correctly installed. This applies both in the case where the user does not type in a scheme (e.g. `example.com`) or they type in the `http` scheme (e.g. `http://example.com`).

Answer (score 2):

I've thought about it for a bit and I see no direct solution for the problem you are having. The cross-origin policy will prevent you from caching it locally, with good reason. If this was not in place you could intercept any requests to other sources.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API says
"Service workers only run over HTTPS, for security reasons. Having modified network requests wide open to man in the middle attacks would be really bad.

As a solution I would host a application cache manifest on http with a redirect to https. This is not automatically cached if the user first comes in through https, but if this is the case the user will most probably always access the page through https. If the user does use http it will cache the redirect and will this will be available offline. Although the technology is deprecated, it is still widely used, reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache .

If a 301 permanent redirect is also used it is unlikely the browser will most likely cache the redirect and load https by default, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301 .

Hopefully this is adequate for your needs, if not I would like to discuss the problems you are facing with this solution.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I accepted another solution though, because it seems to be perfect in my case

Answer (score 1):

If server-side solutions, like returning a HTTP 301 response or including the `Strict-Transport-Security` header aren't possible due to your serving setup, then another option is to use client-side JavaScript to update the `window.location.href`, which will trigger the page to reload.

You can follow the technique used in the [`<platinum-https-redirect>` Polymer element](https://github.com/PolymerElements/platinum-https-redirect/blob/master/platinum-https-redirect.html), which is adapted below:

```
function _isLocalhost(hostname) {
  // !! coerces the logical expression to evaluate to the values true or false.
  return !!(hostname === 'localhost' ||
            // [::1] is the IPv6 localhost address.
            hostname === '[::1]' ||
            // 127.0.0.1/8 is considered localhost for IPv4.
            hostname.match(/^127(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}$/));
}

if (window.location.protocol === 'http:' && !_isLocalhost(window.location.hostname)) {
  // Redirect to https: if we're currently using http: and we're not on localhost.
  window.location.href = 'https:' + window.location.href.substring(window.location.protocol.length);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however it doesn't solve the problem with displaying HTTP content when offline.